# Require form-urlencoded request body with swagger-core

Tags: swagger, dropwizard, swagger-2.0

Using Dropwizard with swagger-core and swagger-jaxrs2 2.2.6, how can you mark the requestBody of a x-www-form-urlencoded request as required?

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/do-something")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
    @Operation(summary = "Does something")
    public void doSomething(@NotNull @FormParam("what") String what) {
      // ...
    }
```

This generates the following:

```js
    "/do-something" : {
      "post" : {
        "summary" : "Does something",
        "operationId" : "doSomething",
        "requestBody" : {

          /* missing here: "required": true */

          "content" : {
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" : {
              "schema" : {
                "required" : [ "what" ],
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                  "what" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses" : { /* ... */ }
      }
    },
```

Parameter `what` is required, however the `requestBody` as a whole is not marked as required. Generated TypeScript clients therefore allow to omit it.

I could annotate the operation with something like `@RequestBody(required = true)`, but this disables the auto detection of the parameters.

Do you have any idea how to solve this without rewriting half the documentation manually?